# Update field in the other table when using form create yii2 is something wrong

Tags: php, forms, activerecord, yii2, active-form

I have three tables, you can see in this picture bellow. And then I've created form skpaa and the data values in form will save to table skpaa and update one the field in the other table. I have the problem to form **SKPAA**, when user save to table skpaa I want the data value in table **anak_asuh** is like **status** changed based on **kode anak asuh** in form **SKPAA**. I've implemented with the following refrences use method [Executing Non-SELECT Queries](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#non-select-queries) from doc yii2. But the result is strange when I save, the all data values in field **status** is changed.  **I want the data value in field status changed based on form SKPAA**. Please tell me how to solutions.. Thanks

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    // Skpaa
    $skpaa = new Skpaa();
    if (!$skpaa) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The skpaa was not found.");
    }

    // Display datetime in form and save to table
    $skpaa->tgl_skpaa = date('Y-m-d');

    // Dispaly kode pengurus in form and save to table
    $skpaa->kode_pengurus = \Yii::$app->user->identity->kode_pengurus;  

    // Ska
    $ska = new Ska(); 
    if (!$ska) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The ska was not found.");
    }

    // Calon Keluarga Asuh
    $calonKeluarga = new CalonKeluargaAsuh(); 
    if (!$calonKeluarga) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The calon keluarga asuh was not found.");
    }

    // Anak asuh
    $anak_asuh = new AnakAsuh();
    if (!$anak_asuh) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The anak asuh was not found.");
    }

    $anak_asuh->kode_anak_asuh = Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('anak_asuh', ['status' => 'Tetap'])->execute();

    // Calon anak
    $calon = new Calon(); 
    if (!$calon) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The Calon was not found.");
    }

    // Calon anak
    $pengurus = new Pengurus(); 
    if (!$pengurus) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The Pengurus was not found.");
    }

    if ($skpaa->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $anak_asuh->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $skpaa->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Data berhasil disimpan!');
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
            return $this->refresh();
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'skpaa' => $skpaa,
        'ska' => $ska,
        'calonKeluarga' => $calonKeluarga,
        'anak_asuh' => $anak_asuh,
        'calon' => $calon,
        'pengurus' => $pengurus,
    ]);
}
```

View :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\widget\Pjax;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\widgets\Select2;
use yii\web\JsExpression;
use app\models\Skpaa;
use app\models\Ska;
use app\models\CalonKeluargaAsuh;
use app\models\AnakAsuh;
use app\models\Calon;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Pengurus;
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;

$this->title = 'Surat Keterangan Penyerahan Anak Asuh';

?>

<h1 align="center">Surat Keterangan Penyerahan Anak Asuh</h1>
<?php
echo "&nbsp";
echo "&nbsp";
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal', 
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{label}\n{beginWrapper}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}\n{endWrapper}",
            'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'label' => 'col-sm-4',
            'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-4',
            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-8',
            'error' => '',
            'hint' => '',
            'button' => 'col-sm-4'
        ],
    ],
    ]); 
?>

<div class="panel panel-default"> 

<div class="panel-heading"><b><h4 align="center">Form Tanda Terima</h4></b></div>

<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')): ?>
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
  <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
  <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Informasi!</h4>
  <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="panel-body">  

<table class="table table-striped"> 

<?php echo $form->field($skpaa, 'no_skpaa')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'readOnly' => true]);
?>

<?= $form->field($skpaa, 'tgl_skpaa')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'tgl_skpaa',
        'style' => 'width:350px',
        'disabled' => true
    ],
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
    'language' => 'id',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        ]
    ]); 
?>

<?php
    $dataSka = ArrayHelper::map(Ska::find()->all(), 'no_ska', 'no_ska');
?>
<?php 
    echo $form->field($skpaa, 'no_ska')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $dataSka,
    'language' => 'id',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Pilih',
        'id' => 'no_ska',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'width' => '350px',
        ],
    ])->label('Nomor Surat Ketersediaan'); 
?>

<?php 
    echo $form->field($calon, 'nama_calon')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php 
    echo $form->field($anak_asuh, 'kode_anak_asuh')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px']);
?>

<?php 
    echo $form->field($calonKeluarga, 'nama')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php 
    echo $form->field($calonKeluarga, 'jenis_kelamin')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php 
    echo $form->field($calonKeluarga, 'alamat')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php 
    echo $form->field($calonKeluarga, 'pekerjaan')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php $kode_pengurus = \Yii::$app->user->identity->kode_pengurus ?>
<?php 
    echo $form->field($skpaa, 'kode_pengurus')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'value' => $kode_pengurus, 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php $nama_pengurus = \Yii::$app->user->identity->nama_pengurus ?>
<?php 
    echo $form->field($pengurus, 'nama_pengurus')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'value' => $nama_pengurus, 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php $alamat = \Yii::$app->user->identity->alamat ?>
<?php 
    echo $form->field($pengurus, 'alamat')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'value' => $alamat, 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php $pekerjaan = \Yii::$app->user->identity->pekerjaan ?>
<?php 
    echo $form->field($pengurus, 'pekerjaan')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'value' => $pekerjaan, 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<?php $jenis_kelamin = \Yii::$app->user->identity->jenis_kelamin ?>
<?php 
    echo $form->field($pengurus, 'jenis_kelamin')->textInput(['style'=>'width:350px', 'value' => $jenis_kelamin, 'disabled' => true]);
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4">
<?= Html::submitButton('Simpan', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
<?php
echo "&nbsp";
echo "&nbsp";
echo Html::a('Keluar', ['/'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
?> 
    </div>
</div>

</table>

</div>

</div> <!-- /panel -->

</div> <!-- /container -->

<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use app\models\Skpaa;
use app\models\Pengurus;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Ska;

class Skpaa extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%skpaa}}';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['no_ska', 'kode_pengurus'], 'required'],
            [['tgl_skpaa'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function actributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            [
                'no_skpaa' => 'Nomor Surat',
                'tgl_skpaa' => 'Tanggal Surat',
                'kode_pengurus' => 'Kode Pengurus',
                'no_ska' => 'Nomor Surat Ketersediaan',    
            ],
        ];
    }

    // Autonumber for no_skpaa
    public function behaviors()
    {
    return [
        [
            'class' => 'mdm\autonumber\Behavior',
            'attribute' => 'no_skpaa', // required
            //'group' => $this->id_branch, // optional
            'value' => 'SKPAA'.'?' , // format auto number. '?' will be replaced with generated number
            'digit' => 2 // optional, default to null. 
        ],

       ];
    }

    public function getPengurus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Pengurus::className(), ['kode_pengurus' => 'no_skpaa']);
    }

    public function getSka()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Ska::className(), ['no_ska' => 'no_skpaa']);
    }
}
```

[image: My tables]

Comment: You probably should use afterSave() method in Skpaa model: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave()-detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('anak_asuh', ['status' => 'Tetap'])->execute();
```

you have not set any condtion so the updated  is executed  on all the rows

You should assigne some condition  for filter the rows  for update eg: assuming that you want update only the row with id = $ id you could use:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('anak_asuh', ['status' => 'Tetap'], 
  'your_id = ' . $id )->execute();
```

Looking at your conde 
I think that you have place the update in the wrong  place try move this code

```
$kode_anak = $anak_asuh->kode_anak_asuh;
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->
    update('anak_asuh', ['status' => 'Tetap'],
            "kode_anak_asuh = '" . $kode_anak  . "'")->execute();
```

inside the code where you load and save the created  models

```
 if ($skpaa->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $anak_asuh->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $skpaa->save()) {
       $kode_anak = $anak_asuh->kode_anak_asuh;
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->
            update('anak_asuh', ['status' => 'Tetap'],
           "kode_anak_asuh = '" . $kode_anak  . "'" )->execute();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Data berhasil disimpan!');
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
        return $this->refresh();
}
```

Comment: I've tried and the result is "Undefined variable: id"

Comment: @Olik   my answer  is a sample you should use the correct name or the table column and for the model var .. could be that the id you need is name $kode_anak_????  or some other name form your schema (this should be you to know) .. and could be you could access using $model->your_code_field .. hope my comment is claer .. to you .

Comment: Yes, you explain is clearly. I've tried but the result is error. "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `anak_asuh` SET `status`='Tetap' WHERE kode_anak_asuh ="

Comment: the error is due to the fact that no value to the variable you chose was not assigned sure to use the correct variable and this contains a correct value.  be sure that $kode_anak   contain the right value  try var_dump($kode_anak)

Comment: @Olik   . i have take a look at your code .. an i have udpated  the answer  with some soggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128735/discussion-between-olik-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I have update the answer  adding quote .."kode_anak_asuh = '" . $kode_anak  . "'"

Answer (score 0):

I adding the code in actionCreate with following answers scaisEdge.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    // Skpaa
    $skpaa = new Skpaa();
    if (!$skpaa) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The skpaa was not found.");
    }

    // Display datetime in form and save to table
    $skpaa->tgl_skpaa = date('Y-m-d');

    // Dispaly kode pengurus in form and save to table
    $skpaa->kode_pengurus = \Yii::$app->user->identity->kode_pengurus;  

    // Ska
    $ska = new Ska(); 
    if (!$ska) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The ska was not found.");
    }

    // Calon Keluarga Asuh
    $calonKeluarga = new CalonKeluargaAsuh(); 
    if (!$calonKeluarga) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The calon keluarga asuh was not found.");
    }

    // Anak asuh
    $anak_asuh = new AnakAsuh();
    if (!$anak_asuh) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The anak asuh was not found.");
    }

    $kode_anak = $anak_asuh->kode_anak_asuh;
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('anak_asuh', ['status' => 'Tetap'], 'kode_anak_asuh = ' . $kode_anak )->execute();

    // Calon anak
    $calon = new Calon(); 
    if (!$calon) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The Calon was not found.");
    }

    // Calon anak
    $pengurus = new Pengurus(); 
    if (!$pengurus) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The Pengurus was not found.");
    }

    if ($skpaa->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $anak_asuh->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $skpaa->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Data berhasil disimpan!');
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
            return $this->refresh();
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'skpaa' => $skpaa,
        'ska' => $ska,
        'calonKeluarga' => $calonKeluarga,
        'anak_asuh' => $anak_asuh,
        'calon' => $calon,
        'pengurus' => $pengurus,
    ]);
}
```